# InnerHTML issue

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

How do I get the values of textboxe's along with `innerHTML`?

For example, if I have

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
        <body>
            <div id="getvalue">
          <p><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></p>
     </div>

       </body>
</html>
```

I need the `innerHTML` of the particlular `id="getvalue"` along with the textbox value.  I got the result if i use

```
var gotvalue=document.getElementBYId('getvalue').innerHTML;
```

I just got the result

```
"<p><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></p>"
```

Also, I need the textbox value along with the `innerHTML`.  How could i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean `document.getElementById('getvalue').innerHTML` right? but I think there might be already similar questions on it here.

Comment: You want to get `value` and `innerHTML` of a `input` element... Something is messy here, input elements have no closing tags and nothing to be used for innerHTML

Comment: Yep, this makes no sense. What do you want here? What is the end result you are trying to achieve??

Comment: I think maybe he's trying to construct the value as part of the string, like: `"<p><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="foo" /></p>"`; the only way I can think to do it is with regex

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward, the OP already has the `innerHTML`, they want to know how to get the `value` property of that `<input>` as well.

Answer (score 6):

You want the [`.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input) of the `<input>` element, like this:

```
var gotvalue = document.getElementById('getvalue').innerHTML;
var inpitvalue = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

Comment: If for some reason you have trouble is a specific browser, try addind a blank value entry so that it knows it has the property to pick up in old IE builds:

Comment: <p><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""></p>

Answer (score 2):

As i can only imagine one halfway good reason for what you need the innerHTML(put it somewhere else into the document for copying), I would suggest to use the DOM-method to get the copy: `cloneNode(true)` and also use a DOM-Method(which one depends on where to put) to inject it into the DOM.
cloneNode() will preserve the attributes too, so the value will also be copied.
If you really need the string, forget this ^^